# How to m validate Form outside the form in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Can anybody have Idea about how can we validate the form from outside the form . example in a page i have a form control and a button control that is out the form how i validate the form on button click .

Answer (score 0):

If your button and form are sharing the same controller the form instance is available inside the controller.

`#` See [Plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/N2l0eOyYm71dUiGA0EJ5?p=preview).